# MySQL SUM calculation not based on number of rows but based on unique results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query below:

```
SELECT COUNT(c.status) as num,
       SUM(p.total_paid_nocred) lordo,
       SUM(p.total_paid) netto
    FROM coupons as c,
        payments as p,
        addresses as a
    WHERE p.payment_id=c.payment_id AND
         c.address_id=a.address_id AND
         c.offer_id='.$off['offer_id'].' AND 
         c.address_id!=0 AND
         a.time <= '.$off['insertion_date'].' AND 
         c.user_id!=0 AND 
         c.status IN (1,2) AND
         a.shipment_num="" AND
         p.status=0 AND
         p.medium!=3
```

The problem I am having is that when this query runs it can find for example 5 coupons, divided between 3 different payment transactions and the other 2 of them in one transaction.

To be clear. The client can buy 3 different coupons with 3 different transactions, or he can buy 2 coupons on one single transaction.

So when the query does the SUM, if a single transaction has 2 linked coupons it duplicates the amount of the transaction for 2. This is not good, because the transaction amount is final as it is, it does not have to get duplicated more times as many coupons are linked to that transaction.

I am trying to use `GROUP BY p.payment_id` but doing this will break the rest of the code working on this query.

How can I force it to SUM only by unique transaction but only for the SUM functions and leave the rest as already it is?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you simplify your example somewhat and add some sample data/a desired result? As it stands now, I'm not quite sure what you're looking for.

Comment: You have to pre-aggregate the values along the two dimensions (`coupons` and `payments`), typically using subqueries in the `from` clause.  Your query is a bit complicated to figure out the best way to do it.

Comment: Not related, and although somewhat subjective I would [suggest looking at ANSI 92 JOIN syntax](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins), the implicit joins you are using are from ANSI 89, and as the name suggests are over 20 years out of date.

Comment: @GarethD thanks I know that. This code has not been done by me indeed ;)